# Extracted my directory files as txt and need to convert to dataframe or csv

Tags: r

[image: txt file]

I have a set of files that I need to use their modified date as an identifier with Rstudio. I was able to extract the directory as a txt file successfully. Now, I need to convert this .txt to .csv. I tried most of the codes but I still have the problem. I need to sparse it into rows and columns ending with a .csv file.

I tried to use different codes but all of them with warnings.

my text file:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                             
-a---l        11/30/2022   4:08 PM          13823 TT3 - 2022-11-30 16-08-36.PL3                              
-a---l        11/30/2022   4:08 PM          13823 TT3  - 2022-11-30 16-08-46.PL3                              
-a---l        11/30/2022   4:08 PM          13823 TT3  - 2022-11-30 16-08-55.PL3                              
-a---l        11/30/2022   4:09 PM          13823 TTT3 - 2022-11-30 16-09-04.PL3
```

this is an example of my needed column names and its data:

```
Mode   -a---l 
Date   11/30/2022          
Time   4:08 PM          
Length 13823  
Name   TT3 - 2022-11-30 16-08-36.PL3
```

Comment: Looks like you could use `read.fwf` to read this fixed-width format, though you'd need to get the names on one read, then call again with `skip=2` to discard the second row of dashes and apply column names from the first call.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it on Python and it worked better for me.